# how can I made URL by using kwargs

Tags: python

This is my problem
you have to use def func!
and print is already defined

```
my_url(sidoname='seoul', key='asdf')
print example)
https://api.go.kr?sidoname=soeul&key=asdf&
```

you have to use

```
def my_url(**kwargs):

   print(my_url(sidoname='seoul', key='asdf'))
```

Comment: See [how to use kwargs](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#using-the-python-kwargs-variable-in-function-definitions).

Comment: Why is `print(my_url(...))` indented inside the function?  This is a recursive call that will never finish.

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_url(**kwargs):
    return base_url + '&'.join(['{}={}'.format(key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items()])

print(my_url(sidoname='soeul', key='asdf'))
```

**output**

```
https://api.go.kr/?sidoname=soeul&key=asdf
```

Answer (score 1):

**kwargs is a dictionary so you should iterate through keys and values and append them to the base url.

```py
def url_builder(base_url: str = "https://api.go.kr?", **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        base_url += key + "=" + value + "&"
    return base_url[:-1]

print(url_builder(sidoname='soeul', key='asdf'))
```

Outputs:

```sh
https://api.go.kr?sidoname=soeul&key=asdf
```

Comment: Superfluous trailing ampersand.

Comment: so much thank you